# How to number the chapter of references and appendixes in Table Of Contents

Tags: sectioning, numbering

Partial code of my main file:

```
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setlength{\headheight}{12pt}
\pagestyle{plain}
\include{chap1} 
\include{chap2}
\include{ch3}
\include{Experiment} % Extract Correlation
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{ \hskip 4em References}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{SpecialStudy}

\newpage
\pagestyle{plain}
\theappendix
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{ \hskip 4em Appendixes}
\include{appendixA_refactoring_approach}
```

With this code I'll get:

```
     // bah bah bah
3    Test0
     3.1 hello
     3.2 hello2
4    Test1
     4.1 Intro
     4.2 Experiment Objective
     4.3 Research Question
     References 
     Appendixes
```

I really want to number References and Appendixes like below. How should I code?

```
3    Test0
     3.1 hello
     3.2 hello2
4    Test1
     4.1 Intro
     4.2 Experiment Objective
     4.3 Research Question
5    References
6    Appendixes
```

Comment: It's been answered on [comp.text.tex](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.text.tex/browse_thread/thread/b6e93d2f5e3a121a)

Comment: You should also provide the class you're using and the packages related to the bibliography (**natbib**, for example). Also the code for the appendix is not clear.

Answer (score 2):

For the standard classes have a look at the [tocbibind](http://ctan.org/pkg/tocbibind) package. Other classes like [memoir](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir) or those from the [KOMA Script](http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) bundle have built-in features. For the appendix you probably need the [appendix](http://ctan.org/pkg/appendix) package in some cases.

Answer (score 2):

If you use the package **apacite**, you can have a numbered bibliography by

```
\usepackage[numberedbib]{apacite}
```

For the appendices, I suggest

```
\chapter{Appendices}
```

and then using `\section` to start each appendix. My studies of Latin make me prefer this form of the plural.